# How to convert array of tags as text wrappers from js code to vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this js code:

```
var tags = [
    'b',
    'i'
    'u',
];

var text = 'some simple text';

tags.forEach(tag => {
    text = '<' + tag + '>' + text + '</' + tag + '>';
});

//print wrapped "text" variable on the page (Upd:) like: <b><i><u>Some text</u></i></b>
```

How to convert this to vue component/template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acceptability of `v-html` depends on the source of markup data. It shouldn't be used with unsanitized, user-defined HTML, doing this is dangerous and may result in script injections.

This is the case for [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html), it allows to build a hierarchy of tags that will be rendered into DOM elements:

```
export default {
  render(h) {
    return tags.reduceRight(
      (wrapper, tag) => h(tag, [wrapper]),
      text
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: My plans was changed and I didn't finish my task with converting js code to vue but If I will need it again in the future I would choose `render` function over `v-html` to achieve the goal. So, I can mark this answer as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Use Your function to generate html code and then simply put result in v-html `<div v-html="xxx" />`  Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML
2. Use dynamic components like this https://jsfiddle.net/Herteby/ffe5rban/  Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

In Your case first option is better choice. Dynamics components are actually designed for Vue components, not raw html tags - but it's possible to use them this way if You really need to.

Comment: How it could be done with dynamic components? It should be some kind of recursive component. `v-html` is the simplest way but doesn't look like the best practice.

Comment: Well, it actually is ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create a computed property called `tagged` and render it inside the template using `v-html` directive :

```js
var app=new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data() {
    return {
      text: "some text"
    };
  },
  computed: {
    tagged() {
      var tags = [
        'b',
        'i',
        'u',
      ];
      tags.forEach(tag => {
        this.text = '<' + tag + '>' + this.text + '</' + tag + '>';
      });

      return this.text;

    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-html="tagged"></div>
</div>
```

Second solution is to create a component with the 3 tags and pass the text as prop :

```js
Vue.component('bui-tag', {
  props: ['text'],
  template: `<b><u><i>{{text}}</i></u></b>`
})


var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data() {
    return {
      text: "some text"
    };
  },
  computed: {
    tagged() {
      var tags = [
        'b',
        'i',
        'u',
      ];
      tags.forEach(tag => {
        this.text = '<' + tag + '>' + this.text + '</' + tag + '>';
      });

      return this.text;

    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <bui-tag :text="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is `v-html` the best option?

Comment: according to your use case and what you have provided it's a good solution, but if you explain more your use case i think there's other solutions

Comment: Second solution isn't a good idea because `tags` array can contains different values, for example, `['b', 'u']` or `['b', 'i']`.

Comment: if these tags don't contain any logic like data binding or events, the v-html is the best solution